# Is there any way I can locate the javascript file once event occurs in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

For eg.

On the page, I have a button with class .class-1 and I have a function for Click for this button on somejsfile.js
'''

```
$('.class-1').on ('click', function() {
alert "Hello";
})
```

'''
I have hundreds of js file on the webpage and Once I click on the button it will show the alert, Hello but I am not sure which JS file contains this function.

Is there any way I can find the Js file based on the event that occurs on the browser.

Thank you.

Comment: use `debugger;`

Comment: If you know the file you add a debugger there and start debugging but I am not sure where the code for this event is. I need something like we can see initiator in xhr-request.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox you can see the click event and if you click on it, it will show you the code and where the code is from.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners